# I am new to Racket and need some help for this function

Tags: racket

I want the answer to be `#t` here:

```
> (is-member? "foo" '(4 5 #f "foo" a))
#t
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
> (is-member? "foo" '(4 5 #f "foo" a))
;string=?: contract violation
;  expected: string?
;  given: #f
;  argument position: 2nd
;  other arguments...:
;   "foo"
```

My definitions of `is-member?` and `is-member-string?` are:

```
#lang racket

(define (is-member? num lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (if (string? num)
          (is-member-string? num lst)
          (is-member-number? num lst))))

(define (is-member-string? num lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (if (integer? (car lst))
          (is-member-string? num (rest lst))
          (if (string=? (car lst) num)
              #t
              (is-member-string? num (rest lst))))))

(define (is-member-number? num lst)
  ....)
```

Comment: The title should say Racket shouldn't it? Also, post all errors and code here as text. Never post images of code.

Comment: Why does your topic say Python and your image say Racket?

Comment: I am sorry I am new here , ok I will change everything sorry again

Comment: If you don't know which type you are comparing use `equal?`. It will return `#t` for two values that look the same. You should not use `string=?` unless you are sure both arguments are strings.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to ask questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at the error message and see how it helps you. It says the error is coming from `string=?`, and if you look in DrRacket it even highlights the specific call that went wrong. It's the `(string=? (car lst) num)` in the `is-member-string?` function.
2. Figure out what arguments were and why they're wrong. The error message says that the wrong argument was `#f` where it expected a string.
3. Where did the bad argument come from? Was it `num` or `(car lst)`? Looking at how `num` flows through the program, `num` should always be `"foo"`, so it's probably the other one, `(car lst)`.
4. How did this code execute with that bad argument? Why is `(car lst)` false here? Because it's walking down the list, and the list contains a false in it. That should be fine, as long as you design your function properly to handle all values.

To do that, you should put a type signature on your functions to show what types of arguments are allowed. For `is-member-string?` I'm assuming you meant:

```
;; is-member-string? : String [List-of Any] -> Boolean
(define (is-member-string? str lst)
   ....)
```

(I've renamed `num` to `str` because it's not a number, it's a string.)

Next you need to make sure that the code works with the signature. You're designing this function by destructuring the list argument, but you need to keep the types of the values in mind:

```
;; is-member-string? : String [List-of Any] -> Boolean
(define (is-member-string? str lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (.... (first lst) ; (first lst) is an Any
       .... (rest lst)))) ; (rest lst) is a [List-of Any]
```

(I'm using `first` instead of `car` because `first` makes more sense.)

Can you see what's wrong now?

```
;; is-member-string? : String [List-of Any] -> Boolean
(define (is-member-string? str lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (if (integer? (first lst))             ; (first lst) is an Any
          (is-member-string? str (rest lst))
          (if (string=? (first lst) str)     ; (first lst) is an Any, but not an integer
              #t
              (is-member-string? str (rest lst))))))
```

`(first lst)` is an `Any`, but you're using `(string=? (first lst) str)`. That shouldn't be allowed unless you're sure that `(first lst)` is a string.

There are two ways to do this. One way to fix this is to use `(equal? (first lst) str)` instead.

```
;; is-member-string? : String [List-of Any] -> Boolean
(define (is-member-string? str lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (if (equal? (first lst) str)
          #t
          (is-member-string? str (rest lst)))))
```

The second way is to check that it's a string before you use `string=?`. I assume that's what you were trying to do with your `integer?` check, but it isn't working. Instead you want to use `(string? (first lst))` somehow. You only want to check `string=?` after that passes. One way to do that is with `and`.

```
;; is-member-string? : String [List-of Any] -> Boolean
(define (is-member-string? str lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (if (and (string? (first lst)) (string=? (first lst) str))
          #t
          (is-member-string? str (rest lst)))))
```

Comment: really thanks a lot and now I know whats my mistake, you explaned everything clearly.  thanks again sir :)